# Find minimum value of a series in a chart

Tags: vba, ms-access, graph

I have a line chart in a sub-form that is loaded into a variety of reports, the chart has 7 series. I have been trying to alter the 'Y' axis minimum value on load, based on the minimum value of all the series but have been unable to find a way to access the series values. I am able to alter the minimum value by entering a value such as 'Me.LineChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 30' but I need to change the value dynamically.

Any pointers on how to get to the values in the data series would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open a recordset of an aggregate query that pulls Min and Max values for filtered dataset then reference fields of recordset.

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT LabNum, First(Blows) As B, Min(A) AS MinOfA, Min(W) AS MinOfW, Min(S) AS MinOfS, Min(F) AS MinOfF, Min(VMA) AS MinOfVMA, " & _
    "Min(VTM) AS MinOfVTM, Min(VF) AS MinOfVF, Max(A) AS MaxOfA, Max(W) AS MaxOfW, Max(S) AS MaxOfS, Max(F) AS MaxOfF, " & _
    "Max(VMA) AS MaxOfVMA, Max(VTM) AS MaxOfVTM, Max(VF) AS MaxOfVF FROM GraphBMD WHERE LabNum='" & strLabNum & "' GROUP BY LabNum;")
```

Or use DMin() domain aggregate function if need only one value.
`intMinD = Nz(Int(DMin("D", "GraphProctor", "Source='Lab' AND LabNum='" & strLabNum & "'")), 0)`

Comment: Thank you June7. The trouble is the graph is in a subreport that will have a variety of datasets as they are loaded into a main report. I'm looking for a way to dynamically access those datasets as the subreport as it is loaded. So far, hours of frustration.

Comment: What do you mean by 'will have a variety of datasets'?

Comment: The subreport is loaded into a number of different reports each with a different set of data. Some datasets will have a Y axis range within 0 and 1, some within the range 1,000 to 1,100. I'm hoping there is a method to inspect the datasets on load so I can set the Y axis minimum value to be other than zero.

Comment: By different dataset do you mean different source tables or just filter of same table? How is subreport RecordSource set on load? Is it just filtered by the master/child links?

Comment: Yes, the datasets are based on queries taking data from different tables. The subreport is loaded into a number of different reports, each with their own resultant dataset. My assumption is that the Chart has access to the results for each series. I've tried interrogating ChartValuesCollection and ChartSeriesCollection trying to find something but to no avail. I also get a lot of 'Object doesn't support this property or method' despite trying to associate with a Chart object.

Comment: Are these tables identical in structure? If so, why not 1 table? Only ways I know to get the data are as I already described. You have not described how you change RecordSource. Should be able to incorporate code that would dynamically build recordset or DSum expression.

Comment: Also, are you using MS-Graph control or Modern Charts?

Comment: The queries take data from a number of different tables resolving into a dataset with similar structures. I am using MS-Graph. I will try using Modern Charts, not looked at these before but they appear to be similar to SSRS charts.

Comment: I will also have another look at your suggested solution. My hope was to be able to modify the subreport but it looks as though I will have to modify all the reports that use the subreport.

Comment: Yes, I can understand chart using query that pulls data from several tables but you seem to indicate there are different tables involved in these various queries. This is where I get lost - why would source tables change? Why multiple queries? Why would would main report(s) have to be modified? I can't use Modern Charts since I still use Access 2010. From what I've read, it's harder to code for Modern Charts.

Comment: Sorry, June7. I've not made myself very clear. The subreport is loaded into a range of main reports to display a variety of data so each subreport, when loaded, has a different dataset. I was hoping to be able to access this dataset from the chart within the subreport. It looks as though I will have to go through each report to modify the individual subreport datasets so that it includes the minimum values. I was hoping to avoid doing this.

Comment: Still not clear to me why datasets are 'different'. Are different tables involved or is it simply different filter criteria? It is possible for code to grab SQL statement from graph RowSource property. Possibly can then use that to set a recordset object and get minimum value of desired field. Edit question to provide sample data and SQL statement.

Comment: The subreport is pulled in to a number of different reports to show changes over time plus various exponential moving averages of those changes for the data I am reporting. for instance, one report may be based on energy use over time, another report based on temperature over time, another report gas cost/kWh over time. Each report would have its own query and dataset. I can either go into each report and amend the queries to include the max or min but was hoping I could get at these values from within the chart object which must use the dataset to draw the graph.

Comment: It would be easier to be able to edit the chart object in the subreport rather than all the individual reports that load the subreport.

Comment: Still not getting my question answered. Are different tables involved for each? Is there an Energy table, Gas table, Temperature table? How does one subreport/chart object manage to display this varied data? Or are there 3 subreport/chart objects? I have indicated several ways for code behind subreport to pull data associated with chart. I have suggested you edit question with data and SQL statement(s). At this point, I have offered all I can and wish you luck with your project.

Comment: Sorry June7, I think it is my fault for not making myself clear. The chart in the subreport has no data. It is only when loaded into the main report that it gets its data so may have any number of data of any type. I have been trying to access this data during the OnLoad event and think I have found it by using the Chart.TransformedRowSource. I will pursue this.